# Text isn't rendering on phones when using CanvasKit on Flutter Web

Tags: android, rendering, flutter-web, canvaskit

I build the Flutter Web app with canvaskit using `flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit` command. However the text isn't rendering properly on some Android phones (e.g. OnePlus 5) using Chrome.

This is the expected result:
[image]

This is the actual result:
[image]

These are the logs:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.9, on macOS 12.5 21G72 darwin-arm, locale en-EE)
    • Flutter version 3.3.9 on channel stable at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/2.10.4/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision b8f7f1f986 (2 weeks ago), 2022-11-23 06:43:51 +0900
    • Engine revision 8f2221fbef
    • Dart version 2.18.5
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/karp/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.0.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14A400
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.73.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.54.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 12.5 21G72 darwin-arm
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 108.0.5359.94

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Are you only seeing this issue in production?

Comment: @BHARATHT yes, this issue occurs only in release mode

Comment: Are you using any custom fonts?

Comment: No, I am not using any custom fonts